# What design pattern is this? Adapter?

Tags: java, c#, design-patterns

[**See below for updates**]

I am having a hard time defining a pattern. My colleague says it's adaptor pattern. I'm not sure. We're stuck mainly because we want to correctly name our components.

Question: **Is it adapter pattern? If not what is it? If it is something else, is this the best way to implement the idea?**

To put it in summary, it is a main component(**is this the adapter?**) that shares an interfaces with sub-components (**are these providers?**). <s>The main components decides/orchestrates which of the sub-components are called</s>. The main component behaves as some sort of "wrapper" to call one of the others that have the same interface. The instances of which are injected through the constructor.

**Assumptions**:

1. For simplicity, we will ignore **DR/IoC** for now, but we understand and apply the pattern/principle.
2. The code is not the best implemented form...feel free to suggest.
3. My use of the words main/sub does not infer some kind of inheritence...just bad naming on my part, if confusing.
4. It's language-agnostic, because I love contributions from C# and Java guys, and the knowledge they share.

I am using a Social Networking scenario where a main component gets stats on a hastag and instantiates the appropriate Social Sub Component (
There is a Social Component interface:

```
ISocialComponent
{
    SomeStatsObject GetStats(string hashTag);
}
```

Social Sub-Components implement ISocialComponent Interface

**Twitter Sub-Component**

```
public class TwitterSubComponent : ISocialComponent
{
    public SomeStatsObject GetStats(string hashTag)
    {
        return SomeMethodThatReturnsStatsObject(hashTag);   
    }

    private SomeMethodThatReturnsStatsObject(string hashTag)
    {
        //... Twitter-specific code goes here
    }
}
```

**Facebook Sub-Component**

```
public class FacebookSubComponent : ISocialComponent
{
    public SomeStatsObject GetStats(string hashTag)
    {
        return SomeMethodThatReturnsStatsObject(hashTag);
    }

    private SomeMethodThatReturnsStatsObject(string hashTag)
    {
        //... Facebook-specific code goes here
    }
}
```

**Instagram Sub-Component**

```
public class InstagramSubComponent : ISocialComponent
{
    public SomeStatsObject GetStats(string hashTag)
    {
        return SomeMethodThatReturnsStatsObject(hasTag);
    }

    private SomeMethodThatReturnsStatsObject(string hashTag)
    {
        //... Instagram-specific code goes here
    }
}
```

**Main Component**

There is a main social component object that calls any one of the Sub-Components (defined below) that implement the shared ISocialComponent interface

```
public class MainSocialComponent : ISocialComponent
{
    //this is an enum
    private RequestedNetwork _requestedNetwork{ get; set;}

    //the SocialComponent instance is injected outside of this class
    private readonly ISocialComponent _socialComponent;

    public MainSocialComponent(ISocialComponent socialComponent)
    {
       _socialComponent = socialComponent;
    } 

    public SomeStatsObject GetStats(string hashTag) 
    {
        return _socialComponent.GetStats(hashTag)

        /**** original code, kept for historical purposes****
        switch(_requestedNetwork)
        {
            case RequestedNetwork.Twitter:
                var twit = new TwitterSubComponent();
                return twit.GetStats(hashTag)
                break;

            case RequestedNetwork.Facebook:
                var fb = new FacebookSubComponent();
                return fb.GetStats(hashTag)
                break;

            case RequestedNetwork.Instagram:
                var in = new InstagramSubComponent();
                return in.GetStats(hashTag)
                break;

            default:
                throw new Exception("Undefined Social Network");
                break;
        }*/
    }
}
```

**Updates:**

I see why some say it is Factory pattern because it is creating objects. I had mentioned that we use an IoC container and DR. It was my mistake to exclude that. I have refactored the code

Comment: *" is this the best way to implement the idea ... feel free to suggest ... I love contributions from C# and Java "* - [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), don't forget to explain what it does.

Comment: [Composite Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)

Comment: (1) Sinatr is right. This is a topic for codereview. (2) Your code could as well well be seen as conforming to _strategy pattern_.

Comment: unrelated: Wouldn't it be beneficial to instead of saving "RequestedNetwork" save an Instance of SubComponents and exchange that only when a different Network is selected? That would be fail-fast in regards to the exception thrown (undefined social network) and you wouldn't have to switch and create an instance in every call to  GetStats

Comment: Looks like anti-pattern :)

Comment: thanks @Sinatr I shall flag it for that

Comment: @blafasel Thanks for your comment, I realised that my statement that we should assume I use IoC/DR, did not fully reflect the intention of how it works, so I see now that my example was a poor one. I have since refactored to reflect IoC and DI.

Comment: @Fildor, you are very right! I realise my example was a poor one. Apologies for that. I have refactored. Please see my update and my comment above

Comment: After Update / Edit I'd say it quite clearly is as close to a Strategy Pattern as you can get.

Comment: @Fildor, quite right! Since blafasel had identified it first, perhaps he can state it as an answer. Please do so as well, and I will upvote.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, this is part of the Factory/Service pattern which is pretty popular for Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control.

Right now though there is no reason to declare your sub components as non static, since you aren't saving your instances to anything.

So it seems to me unless you have missing code where you add the components to a list or something, you could just do this:

```
public static class InstagramSubComponent : ISocialComponent
{
    public static SomeStatsObject GetStats(string hashTag)
    {
        return stuff;
    }
}

public class MainSocialComponent : ISocialComponent
{
    //this is an enum
    private RequestedNetwork _requestedNetwork{ get; set;}

    private static var Mappings = new Dictionary<string, Func<SomeStatsObject>> {
        { "Twitter", TwitterSubComponent.GetStats },
        { "Facebook", FacebookSubComponent.GetStats },
        { "Instagram", InstagramSubComponent.GetStats }
    } 

    public SomeStatsObject GetStats(string hashTag) 
    {
       return Mappings[hashTag].invoke(); 
    }
}
```

}

Now if you are doing stuff like actually saving your instances of sub components to a list for later or whatever, then that changes everything. But I am not seeing that so there's no reason not to just make it all static if these methods are simple.

If they are very complex then you'll want to use dependency injection so you can unit test everything proper.

Comment: Thank-you for your answer. I had already mentioned use of IoC and DR in the assumption. What I have seen to have been misleading is the very fact that I instantiate the "SubComponents" in the "MainSocialComponent"

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can extract creation of `SubComponent` into a `Factory` and pass this `Factory` to `MainSocialComponent`. Inside of the `GetStats` method, you will call `_factory.Create(hashTag);` and than call `GetStats` on the returned object.
This way you'll have factory pattern.

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question.

Comment: Basically, the answer is - what you implemented is more like a factory. Or you can use the strategy easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely **not** an adapter pattern.

An adapter pattern does the following in most cases :

• Works as a bridge between two incompatible interfaces.

• Allows classes with incompatible interfaces work together

Your case is more like a **Factory pattern**. You use high level abstraction and return the type of interface/component whenever you need to.

Comment: @user919426 , Try this and let me know if it makes sense to you.

Comment: _"Try this"_ - try what?

Comment: Ditto what @Fildor said.